# How to animate UISwitch toggle

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to create a custom control that simulates a `UISwitch` with a nicer UX.

Considering the assets are local images, how can I create the animation to translate the image position but also update the asset, background color and text at the same time?

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: @southern-dev: that's not how SO works, you show us what have you tried and then seek help

Comment: Please take the Stack Overflow [tour] and review [ask]. You should probably start by learning how to animate moving a view from left to right... once you've done that, you should be on your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started - the animation matches (close to) the image you linked...

[image]

This is just quickly slapped together, so there is plenty more that could be done.

For example:

- there's currently no `.isOn` type of property
- views are not "rounded"
- `.text`, `.textColor` and `.image` properties are not animatable... to get them to "fade" you could embed them in views and animate the `.alpha` properties
- could also be made `@IBDesignable`

This is all via code - no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections - so to try it out just add this code and set the custom class of a view controller to `MySwitchViewController`:

```
class MySwitch: UIView {

    let thumbView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .center
        v.image = UIImage(systemName: "eye")
        v.tintColor = .black
        return v
    }()

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var offText: String = "Off" {
        didSet {
            theLabel.text = offText
        }
    }
    var onText: String = "On"

    var offColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 205.0 / 255.0, green: 211.0 / 255.0, blue: 217.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    var onColor: UIColor  = UIColor(red: 0.0 / 255.0, green: 92.0 / 255.0, blue: 197.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        addSubview(theLabel)
        addSubview(thumbView)

        leftConstraint = thumbView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0)
        rightConstraint = thumbView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0)

        leftConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        rightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),

            thumbView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),

            thumbView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0),
            thumbView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thumbView.widthAnchor),

            leftConstraint, rightConstraint,

        ])

        backgroundColor = offColor
        thumbView.backgroundColor = .white

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.gotTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    @objc
    func gotTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        // if leftConstraint priority is High, the switch is Off,
        //  which means we are "turning it on"
        let turningOn: Bool = (leftConstraint.priority == .defaultHigh)

        let thumbImageName: String = turningOn ? "checkmark" : "eye"
        guard let thumbImage = UIImage(systemName: thumbImageName) else {
            return
        }
        let bkgColor: UIColor = turningOn ? onColor : offColor

        let newText: String = turningOn ? onText : offText
        let txtColor: UIColor = turningOn ? .white : .black

        leftConstraint.priority = turningOn ? .defaultLow : .defaultHigh
        rightConstraint.priority = turningOn ? .defaultHigh : .defaultLow

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.backgroundColor = bkgColor
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            // these properties are not animatable
            self.theLabel.text = newText
            self.theLabel.textColor = txtColor
            self.thumbView.image = thumbImage
        })

    }

}

class MySwitchViewController: UIViewController {

    let mySwitch: MySwitch = {
        let v = MySwitch()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(mySwitch)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mySwitch.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            mySwitch.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            mySwitch.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            mySwitch.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        ])

        mySwitch.offText = "Mark as read"
        mySwitch.onText = "Marked as read"

    }

}
```

Should at least get you on your way.